# Order of Prepositional Phrases

Tags: prepositional-phrases, sentence-patterns, phrase-order

I wonder whether it would be correct to say:

> I try to practise writing **on a daily basis** *without fail*.

or should the order of the phrases be changed into:

> I try to practise writing **without fail** *on a daily basis*.

Are there any rules concerning the order of prepositional phrases?
Thank you.

Comment: In this case, either one makes sense.

Comment: In the second sentence, it would flow better for me if *without fail* were enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: **@Jason Bassford**, what do you mean? I don't really understand. Why would we need to enclose this phrase in parentheses? Would it be like this: *I try to practise writing, without fail, on a daily basis*?

Comment: I prefer your first example. There's no need for 'parentheses' (round brackets) in either of your examples. Incidentally, there is a third possibility: "I try without fail to practise writing on a daily basis", which I think I prefer to your two.